# How expensive is to update state in Android Jetpack Compose via copy

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

How expensive is it to update state in Android Jetpack Compose like below where you could have over 20 different lists holding about 1000 objects each but you're only updating one list at a time. Aka is it.copy shallow or deep? Aka in below code, would it just shallow copy the references for the 19 other lists and simply deep copy the books list?

```
        _profileState.update {
            it.copy(
                listOfBooks = books
            )
        }
```

Versus directly managing individual list states via separate variables directly inside the view model.

Comment: No deep copies at all, even `listOfBooks` will be just a reference to that `books` list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`copy`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html?ref=lengrand.fr#copying) function creates shallow copies, as also explained and tested in [this blog post](https://lengrand.fr/kotlin-data-classes-shallow-copies-and-immutability/#:%7E:text=TL%3BDR%3A%20The%20data%20class,immutable%20data%20structures%20by%20themselves.).

So as you correctly assumed, it will just copy over the references to the 19 lists, and replaces the old reference to the 20th list with the reference to the `books` list.

---

Also have a look at [`mutableStateListOf()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#mutableStateListOf()). It allows Jetpack Compose to observe changes to a list while keeping that list mutable. So if you declare your list like this, you can directly modify it instead of always assigning a new list:

```
val listOfBooks = mutableStateListOf<Book>()

listOfBooks.add(newBook)  // this will trigger a recomposition
```